# How to set DcInferringLoadBalancingPolicy in CqlSessionBuilder programmatically

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I using 4.4.0 datastax-java-driver. In my scenario, I have to provide contacts points as I am connecting to remote cluster. If I am doing so I am getting following error - `Since you provided explicit contact points, the local DC must be explicitly set.`
I also don't have option to provide this explicitly as I am connecting to different cluster on demand which can be in different data centre. I have found option to set DcInferringLoadBalancingPolicy to infer data centre But I am not sure how to set this in CqlSessionBuilder. Please help me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need be very careful with it - it's mostly for people who are building tools, such as IDEs, etc.  For applications itself it's better to pass datacenter name explicitly - [either via config file, or via Java system property](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.4/manual/core/configuration/).

In short it could be done as following:

```java
ProgrammaticDriverConfigLoaderBuilder configBuilder = 
     DriverConfigLoader.programmaticBuilder();
configBuilder.withClass(DefaultDriverOption.LOAD_BALANCING_POLICY_CLASS,
     DcInferringLoadBalancingPolicy.class);
DriverConfigLoader loader = configBuilder.endProfile().build();
CqlSessionBuilder clusterBuilder = CqlSession.builder()
            .addContactPoints(hosts);
CqlSession session = clusterBuilder.withConfigLoader(loader).build();
```